# Unable to run vue app with mts files - no loaders are configured to process this file

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3

I'm trying to run my Vue app that uses TypeScript and has a bunch of .mts files. Previously, I would manually compile to .mjs with tsc, but I'm hoping I can alleviate the extra step by just running TypeScript directly, however I'm facing the following error:

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.
```

I've tried following various tutorials and setups, but I haven't been able to get this to work.

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "typescript-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-0",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.8.11",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "sass": "^1.32.7",
    "sass-loader": "^12.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "typescript": "~5.0.4"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsxImportSource": "vue",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I even defined a `webpack.config.js` file defining a `ts-loader` (which I installed through npm)

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
};
```

But I'm not able to get it working.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `.mts` filetype to your tsconfig include array and webpack ts-loader config and extension resolution array?